# c# How to have user select folder and then enter

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, path, user-input

I am fairly new to C# so i don't know how to attack this problem.  I have this code, that generates the form so a pop up box comes up and lets you select the folder the user wants to select.  The problem is that after its selected it doesn't give an option to hit enter or hit ok so that the rest of my code can use that folder as a path to execute the remainder of what i want to do.

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.IO;


namespace FolderBrowserDialogSampleInCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BrowseFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
            DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder root = folderDlg.RootFolder;
                var dir = textBox1.Text;

                File.SetAttributes(dir, FileAttributes.Normal);
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf");
                IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> groups = files.GroupBy(n => n.Split('.')[0].Split('_')[0]);

                foreach (var items in groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(items.Key);
                    PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();
                    foreach (var pdfFile in items)
                    {
                        Merge(outputPDFDocument, pdfFile);
                    }
                    if (!Directory.Exists(dir + @"\Merge"))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + @"\Merge");

                    outputPDFDocument.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(items.Key) + @"\Merge\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(items.Key) + ".pdf");
                }
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }

        private static void Merge(PdfDocument outputPDFDocument, string pdfFile)
        {
            PdfDocument inputPDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            outputPDFDocument.Version = inputPDFDocument.Version;
            foreach (PdfPage page in inputPDFDocument.Pages)
            {
                outputPDFDocument.AddPage(page);
            }
        }


    }



}
```

What generates the form to come is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FolderBrowserDialogSampleInCSharp
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that i either have to add in a button in the form design as "enter" or "ok."

Could i just have this so that as soon as the user selects the folder and hits ok the program proceeds to store that as the user selected path?

Comment: @Plutonix here's the thing.  As is, the code just has the user select the folder, and i see the folder path in its text box, but it stops there and does nothing else.  What do i have to add so that the form closes after accepting what the user chose?

Comment: @Plutonix this is exactly what my question was initially.  I have been researching this topic and all sites/videos just pretty much have the same thing where it goes through all the motions of selecting the folder, then poof, nothing. I'm trying to look in my C sharp book to see what coding goes after the user selects folder so that the path becomes a variable i later pass on to iterate PDF merging.

Comment: @Plutonix That is exactly why i am letting the user select a Folder-- it contains all the pdf's that need to be merged based on code that i already have.

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly. After the user selects a folder and presses `Ok` on the dialog, you have the path they selected in the property `folderDlg.SelectedPath`. You can then save this value to a class-level variable if you want to store it, in the same block of code where you're setting it to the `Text` property of a textbox. Where else do you want to store it, and what is preventing you from doing so? What do you want to happen after they select a folder?

Comment: @RufusL Ok, so when i run this, the folder dialogue pops up, it shows "brow folder" and i get to go and choose the folder path.  Once i hit okay, the form does nothing.  It just goes back to the original form/screen showing me the folder's path in the text box, but it does nothing from there.  The only thing i can do from there is just X it out because if i hit enter it just hits the browse folder button again to repeat the entire process.

Comment: Well if you want it to do something, you have to write code to do whatever that is. What do you want it to do??

Comment: @RufusL So i set the textbox1.text to equal my Directory that i want PDF's to be merged in.  This code actually works now because i see the pdf's in my chosen directory being merged, and a new folder within that directory being created for said PDF's.  The only thing is this.  Once i hit okay on choosing the directory the form still stays up showing the path of the directory and doesn't go away.  So this may seem like a trivial thing to ask, but how do i make the form close after i have chosen the directory?  By putting an ok button that closes the form after i have chosen it or something?

Comment: @RufusL i edited my submission with the entire code that i attached my my form/directory button with

Comment: You can just call the form's `Close();` method if you want to close the form after the user dismisses the `FolderBrowserDialog`, but then your application runtime is over (unless you have some other forms hanging around). Don't you want it to do *something* with the path they selected?.

Comment: @RufusL as of now, it does do something with with the path selected.  As soon as its chosen the Merge code goes in full affect.  I also put a Close() thing in it already. But what i really want is that as soon as the path is selected for a console to come up and show the progress of the merges.. thats something im working on right now with the console.writeline/readkey thing.

Comment: Then you might want `Hide()` instead of `Close()`

Comment: @RufusL this might be an off the wall question, but.  I like the command prompt because it prints out what is currently happening with each pdf being merged and the output directory folder is displayed.  Could the form itself contain that exact prompt within the form so that both the command prompt and form are one thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i was searching for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
using System.IO;


namespace FolderBrowserDialogSampleInCSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BrowseFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
            // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
            DialogResult result = folderDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = folderDlg.SelectedPath;
                Environment.SpecialFolder root = folderDlg.RootFolder;





            var dir = textBox1.Text;

            File.SetAttributes(dir, FileAttributes.Normal);
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf");
                IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> groups = files.GroupBy(n => n.Split('.')[0].Split('_')[0]);

                foreach (var items in groups)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(items.Key);
                    PdfDocument outputPDFDocument = new PdfDocument();
                    foreach (var pdfFile in items)
                    {
                        Merge(outputPDFDocument, pdfFile);
                    }
                    if (!Directory.Exists(dir + @"\Merge"))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(dir + @"\Merge");

                    outputPDFDocument.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(items.Key) + @"\Merge\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(items.Key) + ".pdf");
                }
                Console.Read();

                Close();
            }

        }
        private static void Merge(PdfDocument outputPDFDocument, string pdfFile)
        {
            PdfDocument inputPDFDocument = PdfReader.Open(pdfFile, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            outputPDFDocument.Version = inputPDFDocument.Version;
            foreach (PdfPage page in inputPDFDocument.Pages)
            {
                outputPDFDocument.AddPage(page);
            }
        }


    }



}
```